# Stack "transform: translateY" values in GreenSock?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I just came across this wonderful product and realized this is exactly what I need! I have a huge image that is x times the window size, so I want to scroll to the very bottom of it on button click. I would do so with CSS like this:

```
@keyframes {
    to {
        transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(100vh);
    }
}
```

This proved to be a crossbrowser way in CSS instead of:

```
transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 100vh));
```

Is there any way to do so with TweenMax? I do understand that I can calculate these values in pixels and specify them explicitly:

```
var value = -$('img').height() + $(window).height();
var tweenDown = TweenMax.to("img", 5, {y: value});
```

However the advantage of the "stacked" way is that when you resize the window, it keeps the image in the same position.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I could be wrong but I think what you are looking for is `yPercent`. Take a look at this old article when this property was first introduced: https://greensock.com/gsap-1-13-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with for those wondering:

```
TweenMax.to('img', 5, {
  transform: 'translate3d(0,100vh,0)',
  percentY: -100
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[My solution to the bottom]
Actually, with current version of GSAP I think this would be

```
TweenMax.to('img', 5, {
  y: '100vh',
  yPercent: -100
});
```

But, the 'the notes about transforms' documentation section says

> To do percentage-based translation use xPercent and yPercent (added in version 1.13.0) instead of x or y which are typically px-based

https://greensock.com/docs/Plugins/CSSPlugin

Judging by the above,

I think `100vh` for `y` would be interpreted as `100px` when added in the css `matrix` property. In order for this to fully work, I opted for the following:

```
TweenMax.to('img', 5, {
  y: window.innherHeight, // or $(window).heigth()
  yPercent: -100
});
```